# Java StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am writing a program that takes input from a file "items.txt" and adds or removes lines according to "changes.txt" and outputs to another file.

This is the "items.txt" file:

```
101,Nail #1
102,Nail #2
103,Nail #3
104,Hammer Small
105,Hammer Large
```

This is the changes file:

```
A,106,Chainsaw 12"
D,102
d,104
a,107,Chainsaw 10"
```

This is my method that has a problem (`void changes()` is line number 132):

```
void changes() {
    try {
        fileChange = new Scanner(new File("changes.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fileChange.useDelimiter(",|\r|\n");


    while (fileChange.hasNext()) {
        String codeStr = fileChange.next();
        if ((codeStr.charAt(0) == 'D') || (codeStr.charAt(0) == 'd')) {
            delete(fileChange.nextInt());
            System.out.println("delete");
        } else if ((codeStr.charAt(0) == 'A') || (codeStr.charAt(0) == 'a')) {
            add(fileChange.nextInt(), fileChange.next());
            System.out.println("add");
        } //else
            System.out.println("done");
    }

    fileChange.close();
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
add
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
done
```

I added in print statement for "add" and "done" just to help diagnose the problem earlier on. Even though it prints "add" and "done" nothing gets sent to the output file. I would guess that this is due to the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so please be patient with any formatting issues or improper etiquette.

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code. Look at the values it uses when it crashes.

Comment: It's possible that some later iteration throws the exception. (sry, I'm drunk right now.) which line throws the exception?

Comment: You probably try to check the first letter of an empty input (no letters at all).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are using `",|\r|\n"` as the delimiter.
This will return the empty token between the `\r` and the `\n` of your line breaks (assuming you're using Windows-style line breaks). For example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new StringReader("Hello\r\nWorld"));
sc.useDelimiter(",|\r|\n");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String n = sc.next();
    System.out.println(n.length() + " " + n);
}
```

Output:

```
5 Hello
0 
5 World
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/EYaf3l)

So, for those zero-length tokens, you can't read `charAt(0)`, because there is no such character.

Change your delimiter to something like `",|\r\n"`, i.e. treat the `\r\n` as a single delimiter.

Comment: I changed the delimiter to ",|\r\n" and now it will add changes marked "A" and "a" but will not delete changes marked "D" and "d".

Comment: In that case, you might have mixed line breaks. Try `",|\r?\n"`. [It seems to work fine to me if all the line breaks are `\r\n`](http://ideone.com/XwLAJ8).

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `codeStr.isEmpty()` before you ever do a `charAt(0)`.

You are accessing from an empty string.

Something like

```
while (fileChange.hasNext()) {
    String codeStr = fileChange.next();
    if (codeStr.isEmpty()) continue;
```